# Why I receive error: TypeError: Cannot read property of 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the code below I receive the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

```
var _dbCreds = process.env.DB_CREDENTIALS
        .split("|")
        .map(c => c.replace('\|', '|'));
```

Why?

Comment: In your code, it is seems that  ` process.env.DB_CREDENTIALS` is undefined. So, `split()` function does not exists on. I suggest you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before exploring Stack Overflow more.

Comment: Have you set up your `.env` file?

Comment: Yes, I did set up my `.env` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `nodejs` you can read the system's [environment-variables](https://www.bhllinux.com/2020/11/what-are-environment-variables-in-linux.html) using the `process.env` object. You can read more [here](https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs).

It seems that you haven't [set you enviroment variable](https://www.poftut.com/how-to-set-environment-variables-for-linux-windows-bsd-and-macosx/) and that's so, your program fails to find `split function`.

To feel more safe when your app is bootstrapping I suggest you to write your code (more or less) like this:

```
var _dbCreds = process.env.DB_CREDENTIALS;
var _dbCredsSplitted;

if (_dbCreds) {
    _dbCredsSplitted = _dbCreds 
        .split("|")
        .map(c => c.replace('\|', '|'));
} else {
    throw new Error("Database credentials not found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of your variable in the .env file. If it is defined, make sure all the **symbols that need an escape are escaped**.

I had the same issue and it is also reported [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/35818#discussioncomment-2486218).

It seems that this issue occurs since the next.js version 12.1.1.

So, just **put an escape symbol '\'** before each relevant symbol.

For example:

`DB_CREDENTIALS='some_credentials_$'` should be changed to `DB_CREDENTIALS='some_credentials_\$'`